# NoSuchFieldError when using project as a library

Tags: android

I am using [ResideMenu](https://github.com/SpecialCyCi/AndroidResideMenu) as a library project in my main project. My application is crashing with this Exception

**"java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field residemenu_custom of type I in class Lcom/special/ResideMenu/R$layout; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.special.ResideMenu.R$layout' appears in /data/data/org.progos.creoroom/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4_1a4c9aca82e857a1109baf42a8440f521d6f33d4-classes.dex)"**.

There are some thread on SO that says if you have resouce with same name in your app (main app) module and in your library module you will face that Error but that's not case with my project. I have no idea what cause this problem, any help will be great.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue just now and I simply did a `clean project` and then ran it as normal. This fixed it for me, hopefully this will help others.